# How to share one folder of dropbox to another dropbox in android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api, file-sharing, data-sharing

I am working on an android application in which i have successfully sync my files to my dropbox account using dropbox sync API.
Now at the same time i have any other dropbox account and i want that all the saved file at my dropbox will share or sync to that another dropbox account.

i.e. If i have dropbox account A and B.From android application my files is syncing to account A, so how can i sync or shared same files on account B from my account A at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross linking for reference: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=118449